# Check every row for each column values in a df in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas data frames. So, I need help in this
I have a df like below stated:

```
  Location      A      B      C      D
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED
2        Z  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
```

I want the status column for every row and for every column in data frame. Status column is based on  col A, B, C and D. If any of the column value in a row is RED, then Status is RED. Else if any of the column value is amber, then the status is amber, else green.

For each column, the output will be red when any of the value in that column is red. Else if any of the column value is amber, then value is amber. Else column value will be green.

The output should be like this

```
  Location      A      B      C      D  Status
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER     RED
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED     RED
2        Z  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN   AMBER
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN   GREEN
            GREEN    RED    RED    RED
```

Answer (score 3):

Idea is create list of priority values, reshape values by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), convert to categoricals, sorting and get first values by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
priority = ['RED','AMBER','GREEN']
c = ['A','B','C','D']
s = df[c].stack()

cats = pd.Categorical(s, ordered=True, categories=priority)
df['Status'] = pd.Series(cats, index=s.index).sort_values().groupby(level=0).first()
print (df)
  Location      A      B      C      D Status
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER    RED
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED    RED
2        Z  GREEN  AMBER  GREEN  GREEN  AMBER
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) along axis 1:

```
condlist = [
    df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].eq('RED').any(1),
    df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].eq('AMBER').any(1)
]

choicelist = ['RED', 'AMBER']

df['Status'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='GREEN')
```

[out]

```
  Location      A      B      C      D Status
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER    RED
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED    RED
2        Z  GREEN  GREEN  AMBER  GREEN  AMBER
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def set_status(row):
  condition = [row['A'], row['B'], row['C'], row['D']]
  if 'RED' in condition:
    return 'RED'
  elif 'AMBER' in condition:
    return 'AMBER'
  else:
    return 'GREEN'

df['Status'] = df.apply(set_status, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `df` looks like this:

```
  Location      A      B      C      D
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED
2        Z  GREEN  GREEN  AMBER  GREEN
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
```

you can define your own function in order to use it as a parameter in [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Usage of this method ensures, you can use your predefined function to both rows and columns, which is exactly your case.

The code is following:

```
# predefined function
def get_status(axis):
    for val in ['RED', 'AMBER', 'GREEN']:
        if val in axis.values:
            return val
    return 'Status'

# addition of Status row and column
df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(lambda col: get_status(col), axis=0).to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_status(row), axis=1)
```

The final output is following:

```
>>> print(df)
  Location      A      B      C      D Status
0        X  GREEN    RED  GREEN  AMBER    RED
1        Y  GREEN    RED    RED    RED    RED
2        Z  GREEN  GREEN  AMBER  GREEN  AMBER
3        R  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN  GREEN
4   Status  GREEN    RED    RED    RED    RED
```